# Django - (Restrict content from blocked users) Cannot unpack non-iterable ManyRelatedManager object

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

Hey guys I want the view to not show contents of blocked users, but I am getting an error like this:
How can I restrict the content from not showing in the template? Please have a look at the views.

```
TypeError at /videos/all_videos/
cannot unpack non-iterable ManyRelatedManager object
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/videos/all_videos/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
cannot unpack non-iterable ManyRelatedManager object
```

views

```
class AllVideoView(ListView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = VideoPost
    template_name = 'videos/users/all_video_view.html'
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AllVideoView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        current_user = self.request.user
        video_list = VideoPost.objects.exclude(current_user.profile.blocked).order_by('-post_date')
        paginator = Paginator(video_list, self.paginate_by)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            videos = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            videos = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            videos = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        context = {
             'page':page,
             'videos':videos,
             }
        return context
```

I understood one thing that I called the video_list wrong. can anyone tell me how to properly do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the problem.

```
    blocked_ids = self.request.user.profile.blocked.values_list('id',flat=True) 
    video_list = VideoPost.objects.exclude(user_id__in=blocked_ids).order_by('-post_date')
```

changed the video_list like this to restrict the blocked content.